# Not able to connect to mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

Every time if my server restarts by mistake or I stopped and then restart I'm not be able to connect to my mongodb. I get this below error and according to this 27017 port is not open but in my security group I opened this port.

````
MongoDB shell version v5.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1```

So, I don't know what I'm doing wrong please help me because I'm facing this issue from very long time and to rid of this I've to always setup new mongodb
````

Comment: The MongoDB does not start at boot. Did you define the mongod as service and did you enable it? Are you running on Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the MongoDB as service and set to automatic start.

On Windows add lines similar to

```
processManagement:
  windowsService:
    serviceName: mongod
    displayName: MongoDB
    description: MongoDB Server
```

to your configuration file (typically `mongod.conf` or `mongod.cfg`), if not already existing.
Then the easiest way to install the service is running

```
mongod.exe --config <your config file> --install
```

On Linux (Redhat, Centos, etc.) it works like this.

- Copy default service file

  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service`
- Customize service file `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service`, if needed
- Enable the service: `systemctl enable mongod`
- Start the service: `systemctl start mongod`

Comment: Getting error

```[root@mongo-dev ~]# systemctl enable mongod
Failed to execute operation: File exists```

Comment: also if I'm running mongo I'm now getting some extra lines

```{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-28T09:50:35.794Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":false}}}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and put such additional information there instead of adding a comment. This messages seems to be a bug in MongoDB 5.0, see [Occasionally getting "Initialized wire specification" when connecting](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-60551) - you can ignore it.

Comment: Okay sorry for that, but still I'm not be able to connect to my mongo